# Show content on example.com from a sub directory

Tags: domains, php, apache, subdomain, directory

I have a domain that looks like `example.com`
on the server files look like:

```
<www>
 <mydirectory>
 <otherstuff>
 <asubdomain>
 index.html
 .htaccess
```

When you open the site, it will display `index.html`.

My question is: how can I make it so it displays `mydirectory/index.php`, without affecting the scripts inside that directory (it's Wordpress)?

Comment: also note that the script inside that directory assumes that it's installed on `domain.com` (not `domain.com/mydirectory`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a rule in your .htaccess file to handle it. This may help out http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/10/06/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-via-htaccess/

Comment: You probably should elaborate on that a bit and show an example or link to one.